# Problems booting in recovery mode with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, boot, udev, recovery-mode, modprobe

This is what I get when I boot into recoverymode:

```
udevd[369]: timeout: killing '/sbin/modprobe/ -bv pci:v00001002d00006738sv0000174
Bsd0000174Bbc03sc00i00' [374]
```

It shows multiple times.

[image: picture]

Comment: What happens after that? Do you keep getting those messages infinitively or it stops in some moment and freeze there?

Comment: No I keep getting them  infinitively, the recovery menu is there, I can use it if I press up and down arrow keys, but the lines keep coming again in my way..ps:thx for reply.